# asp.net microsoft report viewer: how to group rows in a table and do subtotals?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

So I have a table control in report viewer with a dataset that has a list of a class with property fields A,B.

A is a string and B is an integer.

Now I populate a list and pass it to the report.

What I want is that the table should contain rows grouped by field A and show a subtotal row (with double borders) for each category of Field A, summing over Field B.

Is this even possible in microsoft report viewer?

Comment: it is possible, they are called Expressions. Now you can do more research....

Comment: Actually I found the solution, you just need to create a parent group for a row group and then table rows group up just as I wanted.